# Get Url Fragment on server side in C#

Tags: c#, session, url, hash, httprequest

I do NOT get url fragment (i.e. Hash URL) in `HttpActionExecutedContext.Request.Headers.Referrer.Fragment` in Mozila Firefix browser. ( But it is working fine in Chrome and IE11.)

Can anyone please suggest that how can I get Url fragment (i.e. hash url) of the web page on server side (in `C#` code) at the time of session timeout.

I have created a website using Web API and have to implement below requirement is below:
Suppose `Session timeout` occurs when user was on page X. So user gets logout automatically and is redirected to login page. Now after the successful login, the user should be redirected to page X (where he was when `session timeout` occurred).

Comment: Do you see `<meta name="referrer" content="origin">` in the source of the referrer page?

Comment: No, there is no such element in the source of the referrer page. In fact, this element is not present in source of any page.